# Automatically Pack Javascript/CSS from Amazon S3?

Tags: php, javascript, optimization, amazon-s3, packing

I'm moving my javascript and css files to Amazon S3 - can anyone suggest an efficient way to automatically pack/minimize the files without defeating the purpose of hosting them on S3?

Atm, I have my javascript files being called in this manner:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjavascript.js.php"></script>
```

Where the php file finds myjavascript.js, packs it, saves the packed js (myjavascript_min.js) into a separate folder, and returns it. This doesn't seem very efficient, even though it only goes through the packing process if either myjavascript_min.js doesn't exist or myjavascript.js has been modified after myjavascript_min.js was last generated.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: what is the above code line for? are you including a JS or PHP or a Mixture of BOTH?

Comment: That's just what I'm using now so you get an idea of what I'm after. The php packs and returns the javascript.

Comment: ohk. so this PHP script is not performing as you want?

Comment: It's working fine so far but I wanted to optimize further by hosting on Amazon S3, and wanted to know if I can do something similar to what I'm doing now, except the file being hosted on Amazon.

Comment: You mean to say that is there any other alternative to Amazon S3?

Comment: Well, currently, the javascript files are hosted on my web server. Basically I just want to offload as much onto Amazon as possible (if it's worth it).

Comment: Are there too many files and consuming too much of server bandwith?

Comment: It's not bad now as the site is still in beta and doesn't have a whole load of traffic. But, I figure once I have thousands of users online simultaneously it'll be noticeably sluggish as opposed to if I were to setup something on Amazon S3.

Comment: Good thought. But i need some time to think upon this. I will answer a bit later. If meanwhile someone answers then its OK. But i wont be able to answer this question so fast.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, thank you.

Comment: @mista_sage - thanks? for what? Its good to find people like you who ask such questions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a build script that packs, minifies and pushes to S3 each time a new copy is pushed live. Change all your references to the minified versions on S3 and you should be good to go.

Comment: I guess that's where I need advice then -- how to automatically pack and upload to S3 when a change is made.

Comment: Take your current script that packs and minifies, add code to push the files to S3 and run it each time you push a new version of your website. Depends on how you push a new version. You could have a cronjob that watches your JS and CSS directories for changes or create a script that updates your website and pushes files to S3.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/